# Create segmented circle in Adobe Illustrator and have each segment be a different color

Tags: adobe-illustrator

As the title mentions I need to create a pie of sorts using Adobe Illustrator. It seems like it would be easy using the Polar Grid Tool but I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to make each 'piece' of the pie be into its own independant object/layer/etc. I need each piece to be independantly editible for color/content/text/etc. Please help an AI noob....

Answer (score 0):

Illustrator provides several [Graph Tools](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS3f28b00cc50711d9fc86fa8133b3ce158e-8000.html). One option is a pie chart.

> Graphs let you communicate statistical information in a visual way. In Adobe Illustrator, you can create nine different types of graphs and customize them to suit your needs. Click and hold the graph tool in the Tools panel to see all different types of graphs you can create.

Answer (score 0):

Use the graph tool, fill in your percentages:

[image]

Use the direct selection tool (the white arrow) to colour your pie pieces. Or you could do `object` -> `expand` to "dissect" your circle.

[image]